# How do I develop a plugin for a library when including it as a peerDependency gives me no concrete implementation to use?

Tags: javascript, npm, peer-dependencies

**The Requirements:**

I am developing a plugin for `popularLibrary.js`. The plugin:

- Will not work, at all, if `popularLibrary.js` is not present
- Works with `v1.x.x` of `popularLibrary.js`
- Must work if it's included as a dependency in a project that uses `popularLibrary.js`
- Must work if it's included as a packaged source alongside `popularLibrary.js`

In example:

```
<script src="https://some-cdn.com/popularLibrary.js"></script>
<script src="https://some-cdn.com/myMagicalPlugin.js"></script>
```

**The Problems:**

- When I set `popularLibrary.js` as a `peerDependency`, it is no longer downloaded on `npm install`. How do I continue to develop my plugin when it needs to import and utilize functionality that exists in `popularLibrary.js`?
- Not everyone uses a build step. If someone adds the minified sources for `popularLibrary.js` and `myMagicalPlugin.js`, how does that `peerDependency` resolve? Do I need to do anything extra/special in either library to support this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a while since I originally asked this. I ultimately added that same `peerDependency` as a `devDependency`, as it's needed to develop and test the application.

Ideally, you program to some contract/interface to decouple the plugin from the primary library as much as possible. In a more concrete example, I have two WebPack scripts.

Script 1: Bundles the library and uses `excludes` key for any direct dependencies on the primary library (should be avoided if you can help it, ie. Decoupled)

Script 2: For a dev application, uses the primary library, and imports the plugin from source. Used with webpack-dev-server for development/testing

You can use WebPackBundleAnalyzer to make sure you're not accidentally bundling peerDeps